# Media Query seem to be inactive using bootstrap with yii2

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, yii2

let's have a look to following 2 pictures, please. First one will show my website on big screen,second one on smartphone:
[image]

[image]

I have to touch eleven(!!) times on smartphonescreen in order to get all informations. Why is mediaQuery of bootstrap not doing it's job? I want to compress table illustration at smartphone, but not at big screen. Any ideas, how to achieve my intention? Here is layout file:

```html
<?php

use yii\helpers\Html;
use common\classes\AssetBundle;
?>
<?php
AssetBundle::register($this);
?>
<?php $this->beginPage() ?>
<!Doctype html> <!-- Definition des doctype-Modus -->
<html> <!-- Definition des Stammverzeichnises -->
    <head> <!-- Definition des Kopfbereiches -->
        <meta charset="utf-8"> <!-- charset[utf-8:]  definiert den deutschen Zeichensatz -->
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
        <title><?= Html::encode($this->title) ?></title>
        <style>
            body{
                background-color: #D8D8D8 !important;
            }
        </style>
        <?php $this->head() ?>
    </head>
    <body>
        <?php $this->beginBody() ?>
        <?= $content ?>
        <?php $this->endBody() ?>
    </body>
</html>
<?php $this->endPage() ?>
```

Here is Assetclass:

```html
<?php

namespace common\classes;

class AssetBundle extends \yii\web\AssetBundle {

    public $basePath = '@webroot';
    public $baseUrl = '@web';
    public $css = [
            //'css/font-awesome.min.css',
            //'css/lightbox.min.css'
    ];
    public $depends = [
        'yii\web\YiiAsset',
        'yii\bootstrap\BootstrapAsset',
        'yii\bootstrap\BootstrapPluginAsset',
    ];

    public function init() {
        parent::init();
        $this->publishOptions['beforeCopy'] = function ($from, $to) {
            return preg_match('%(/|\\\\)(fonts|css)%', $from);
        };
    }
}
```

**Rephrasing** question:
Also including `<div class="table-responsive"></div>` won't fix problem. Here is my GridView. There isn't another div-tag any more ,but this one!

```html
<div class="table-responsive">
    <?=
    GridView::widget([
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
        'filterModel' => $searchModel,
        'columns' => $gridColumn,
        'tableOptions' => ['class' => 'table-responsive'],
        'responsiveWrap' => true,
        'panel' => [
            'type' => GridView::TYPE_PRIMARY,
            'before' => Html::a('<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i> zur Übersicht', ['/immobilien/preview'], ['class' => 'btn btn-info']),
            'after' => Html::a('<i class="fa fa-spinner fa-pulse fa-2x fa-fw"></i>Termin vereinbaren', ['/immobilien/termin'], ['class' => 'btn btn-success']),
            'heading' => '<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-book"></span>  ' . Html::encode($this->title),
            'class' => 'danger'
        ],
        'toolbar' => [
            '{export}',
            '{toggleData}'
        ],
    ]);
    ?>
</div>
```

Here are two more Screensots. First one seems to be acceptable. Minimizing screen a little bit will destroy everything. I'm really frustrated using yii2/bootstrap. This shouldn't occur !

```
  'responsiveWrap' => true,
```

wont't fix problem, too!

[image]

[image]

Comment: What kind of magical solution you're expecting here from Twitter Bootstrap? These are tables, the only generic solution is to add horizontal scroll, and you already got this. If you care about responsiveness you should not use tables in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

In the bootstrap documentation, you can find that

> Responsive tables Create responsive tables by wrapping any .table in
>   .table-responsive to make them scroll horizontally on small devices
>   (under 768px). When viewing on anything larger than 768px wide, you
>   will not see any difference in these tables.

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/css/#tables-responsive

So in your view write this

```
<div class="table-responsive">
// GridView here
</div>
```

Comment: won't fix problem( See rephrasing question above)

Comment: Ok left me to find other soulution

Comment: In your  grid  option changes the table class `<?= GridView::widget([
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
        'filterModel' => $searchModel,,
        'tableOptions' => [
            'class' => 'table-responsive'
        ],
...`

Comment: Didn't fix problem,too. I already published this option in rephrasing above :=(

Comment: Please set try this in your `GridView::widget` option  `'responsiveWrap' => true`,
This is: responsiveWrap: boolean, whether the grid table columns will be responsively wrapped to a single column for small screen devices (less than 480px). Defaults to false

Comment: Won't change anything! See rephrasing

Comment: you can try http://demos.krajee.com/grid#table-styling here you can find the responsive attribute and responsiveWrap

Comment: I know about these options of kartik,long since. I tried all of them! But they seem to be absolutely ineffective! Should I try to deactivate bootstrap or coding this site without using yii2?

Answer (score 0):

In most cases a smartphone screen is too small to display more than one or two columns.

My solution is to have a different layout for smartphones:

```
$isMobile = (\Yii::$app->devicedetect->isMobile() and !(\Yii::$app->devicedetect->isTablet()));
if ($isMobile) {
    $columns = "column1,column2";    
}
else {
    $columns = "column1,column2,column3,column4,column5";
}

$columns = explode(",", $columns);
..
```

Devicedetect: https://github.com/alexandernst/yii2-device-detect

Comment: If you want to hide some columns on small screens, it is better to do it using CSS and media queries.